# Use Python Pandas to add calculated rows to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks somewhat like this:

```
Date    Content Count
3/20/16 Apple   16
3/20/16 Banana  13
6/20/17 Apple   16
6/20/17 Banana  10
8/10/19 Apple   5
8/10/19 Banana  3
```

I am trying to calculate the ratio for each date and add them as new rows. So the end product would look like this:

```
Date    Content Count
3/20/16 Apple   16
3/20/16 Banana  13
3/20/16 Apple/Banana    1.23
6/20/17 Apple   16
6/20/17 Banana  10
6/20/17 Apple/Banana    1.6
8/10/19 Apple   5
8/10/19 Banana  3
8/10/19 Apple/Banana    1.67
```

The new rows could go anywhere in the dataframe and do not have to be directly underneath each date. They can be added to the bottom of the dataframe. I just need to figure out how to calculate the ratio of apple to banana for each date.

I assume I'd have to group by date and append, but I am not sure how to put those together.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: does each date always have one `Apple` and only one `Banana`, and nothing else?

Comment: @CypherX that's correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Try this. I used slightly different dummy data to test the solution. The dummy-data is also provided below for reproducibility.

```py
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['Count'] = df.loc[df.Content == 'Apple'].set_index('Date')['Count']/df.loc[df.Content == 'Banana'].set_index('Date')['Count']
df2['Content'] = 'Apple/Banana'

df.append(df2.reset_index(drop=False))
```

**Output**:

```sh
      Date       Content      Count
0  3/20/16         Apple  16.000000
1  3/20/16        Banana  13.000000
2  3/22/16         Apple  20.000000
3  3/22/16        Banana  10.000000
0  3/20/16  Apple/Banana   1.230769
1  3/22/16  Apple/Banana   2.000000
```

### Dummy Data

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """
Date,Content,Count
3/20/16,Apple,16
3/20/16,Banana,13
3/22/16,Apple,20
3/22/16,Banana,10
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=',', infer_datetime_format=True)
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```sh
      Date Content  Count
0  3/20/16   Apple     16
1  3/20/16  Banana     13
2  3/22/16   Apple     20
3  3/22/16  Banana     10
```

Comment: Not working for me. I get this error: KeyError: 'Count' with the first line.

Comment: @sgy01220 Made correction. Please check now. There was a bug.

Comment: @sgy01220 Please consider **`voting up`** as well.